# if the limit of f doesnt exist then there are curves st the limit of f restricted to those curves doesnt exist

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is it true that if $f: G \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, with $n \geq 2,$ and $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$, does not exist, then

1. There exists a $1-1$ curve $\phi:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\phi(0)=a$ and $$\lim_{t \to 0} f \circ \phi (t)$$ does not exist, or
2. There are two $1-1$ curves $\phi_1,\phi_2: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\phi_1(0)=\phi_2(0)=a$ and $$\lim_{t \to 0} f \circ \phi_1 (t) \neq \lim_{t \to 0} f \circ \phi_2 (t)?$$ The above statement is a reciprocal of the well-known theorem that asserts that if either of two conditions are satisfied then the limit of $f$ does not exists.

One way to prove it would be

1. To consider a sequence $(a_k)$ such that $a_k \to a$ as $k \to \infty $ and $\lim_k f(a_k)$ does not exist then to consider a 1-1 curve that contains the sequence $(a_k)$.
2. To consider two sequences $(a_k),(b_k)$ such that $a_k, b_k \to a$ as $k \to \infty$ and $\lim_k f(a_k) \neq \lim_k f(b_k)$, then to consider two 1-1 curves that contains $(a_k)$ and $(b_k)$ respectively.

The problem is that I do not know that if it possible to consider such a curves in such a way to be 1-1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "1-1 curve"? I think even the first point should be sufficient. If the limit of $f$ does not exist, you always find a curve on which it does not exist, by the argument you gave yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)$ does not exist then by Cauchy's criterion for functions there is an $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for any $\delta>0$ you can find two points $x$, $y$ with $0<|y|\leq |x|<\delta$ such that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\geq\epsilon_0\ .$$
We now construct recursively a sequence $$\sigma:=(x_0,y_0,x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,\ldots)$$ satisfying $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\geq\epsilon_0$ for all $n\geq0$, and converging to $0$. To this end put $\delta:=1$ and choose $x_0$, $y_0$ such that $0<|y_0|\leq |x_0|<\delta_0$ and $|f(x_0)-f(y_0)|\geq\epsilon_0$. The recursion step is as follows: When  for some $n\geq0$ the points $x_n$, $y_n$ have been chosen put $\delta:=\min\{2^{-n}, |y_n|\}$ and choose $x_{n+1}$, $y_{n+1}$ such that $0<|y_{n+1}|\leq |x_{n+1}|<\delta$ and $|f(x_{n+1})-f(y_{n+1})|\geq\epsilon_0$.

After the sequence $\sigma$ has been constructed connect its points successively by arcs of concentric circles or logarithmic spirals. The resulting curve will be injective, converge to $0$,  and even have finite length.