# If the limit along all continuous paths is $0$ for $f(x,y)$, must the limit actually be $0$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Say we have $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ i.e. $z=f(x,y)$.

We know that the limit $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ exists and is equal to $0$ for all continuous paths then can we conclude that the double limit is *actually* $0$ ? Why or why not?

I feel that the answer should be *yes* as even for functions discontinuous at origin, the *limit* should exist. I can't prove it rigorously though. Any suggestions?

Comment: See also the following question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416520/if-the-limit-of-f-doesnt-exist-then-there-are-curves-st-the-limit-of-f-restricte/2416708#2416708

Answer (score 1):

Suppose it is not zero, there exists $c>0$ such that for every integer $n>0$, there exists $x_n$ with $\|x_n\|<1/n$ and $|f(x_n)|>c$ you can construct a path $c$ with is the concatenation of  paths between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ (you parameterize $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ with $c_i:[1/(i+1),1/i]$ such that $c_i(1/(i+1))=x_{i+1}$ and $c_i(1/i)=x_i$) to which you add $c(0)=0$. The limit at $0$ is not zero, contracdition.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L:= \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)$, $I$ an intervall in $ \mathbb R$, $t_0 \in I$ and $c:I \to \mathbb R^2$ a continuous path such that $c(t) \to (0,0)$ for $t \to t_0$.

Let $\epsilon >0$. Then there is $ \delta >0$ such that $0<||(x,y)|| < \delta$ implies that $|f(x,y) -L| < \epsilon$.

There is some $d>0$ with $||c(t)|| < \delta$ for $0<|t-t_0|<d$.

Hence, for $0<|t-t_0|<d$, we have

$|f(c(t)) -L| < \epsilon$.

This means: $f(c(t)) \to L$ for $t \to t_0$.

Does this answer your question ?