# Converse of path test for multivariable limits.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm familiar with the fact that, if $\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)} f(x,y)$ exists and is equal to some scalar $L$ and $r:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a function such that $\lim_{t\to 1} r(t) = (x_0,y_0)$, then the limit $\lim_{t\to 1} f(r(t))$ also exists and is equal to $L$. It can be easily proven with the $\varepsilon -\delta$ definition of limits. This allows to show the non-existence of $\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)} f(x,y)$ by showing the limit respect some path does not exist, or by showing that two paths lead to different limits.

My question is: is the converse true? If $\lim_{t\to 1} f(r(t))=L$ for all paths $r:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\lim_{t\to 1} r(t) = (x_0,y_0)$, can I conclude the existence of the multivariable limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)} f(x,y)$? If so, how could I prove it?

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203219/limit-along-a-path-equivalent-to-usual-definition-of-limit, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416520/if-the-limit-of-f-doesnt-exist-then-there-are-curves-st-the-limit-of-f-restricte/2416708

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks, I didn't see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Suppose that you *don't* have $\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}f(x,y)=L$. Then there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for every $\delta>0$, there is some $(x,y)\in B_\delta(x_0,y_0)$ such that $\bigl|f(x,y)-L\bigr|\geqslant\varepsilon$. In particular, for every $n\in\Bbb N$, there is some $(x,y)\in B_{1/n}(x_0,y_0)$ such that $\bigl|f(x_n,y_n)-L\bigr|\geqslant\varepsilon$. Now, consider the path $r\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\Bbb R^2$ such that:

- if $t\in\left[0,\frac12\right]$, $r(t)=(1-2t)(x_1,y_1)+2t(x_2,y_2)$;
- if $t\in\left[\frac12,\frac34\right]$, $r(t)=(3-4t)(x_2,y_2)+(4t-2)(x_3,y_3)$;
- if $t\in\left[\frac34,\frac78\right]$, $r(t)=(7-8t)(x_3,y_3)+(8t-6)(x_4,y_4)$;
- $\vdots$
- $r(1)=(x_0,y_0)$.

Then $r$ is continuous and, since$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\left|f\left(r\left(1-\frac1{2^n}\right)\right)-L\right|\geqslant\varepsilon,$$you *don't* have $\lim_{t\to1}f\bigl(r(t)\bigr)=L$.

Comment: Somef typos here.

Comment: @zhw. I was abel to find two. Are you aware of more?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos In the last formula it should say $f(r(1-1/2^n))$ instead of $f(1-1/2^n)$, and $\varepsilon$ instead of 0.

Comment: @ted I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: third line, that should be $f(x,y)$ there

Comment: @zhw I was about to say that it should be $(x_n,y_n)$ instead of $(x,y)$, since these are the elements in the sequence he used to define $r$.

Comment: @zhw. Indeed. Thank you.

Comment: @ted Yes, the fourth line should have $f(x_n,y_n)\in B_{1/n}(x_0,y_0)$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks, your proof is very clear.